# Why it doesn't shows color in navigation-bar?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Ratnakar Pharma</a>
        </div><!--Navbar Header End -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#products">Our Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--End Container-->
</nav><!-- End Navbar-->
```

This is CSS Code:

```
.navbar-inverse{
    background-color:#2C3E50;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{
    color:white;
}
```

I gave my custom css code. And tried to change background-color of my navigation bar. But it doesn't work. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I see no issue too , http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNRVqb

Comment: add your custom css link after bootstrap 's css link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your custom css file after Bootstrap css file. Then it works.

> https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code to this , it works now , A background image was applied by bootstrap , i removed that

```css
.navbar-inverse{
    background-color:#2C3E50;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
      background-image: none!important;
    color:#FFFFFF}
```

Comment: When using bootstrap (or in general) it is a bad idea to use `!important` since it can't be overwritten again.